# How to add a number and a cell value in memory

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 116

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = "=R!$B$" & CStr(i + 1) + 0.75
    End With

    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm trying to have this automatically assign a border to a chart series depending on a value in a corresponding cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value from the cell as a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
.Weight = sheets("R").Range("B" & CLng(i + 1)).value + 0.75
```